# Ngx-Charts line chart hide the visible bar of the currently activated circle

Tags: ngx-charts

I am creating a line chart using ngx-charts. When i hover to one of the data points in the graph, it displays a circle but also displays a bar below the active circle.

I would like to hide that visible bar.

Can it be possible with some config attributes or using modifying css?